# How can I use this for loop to correctly print the closest K integers to X?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr;
}

public static int findElement(int[] arr, int x) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = arr.length;
    int mid = 0;
    while (start <= end) {
       mid = (start + end)/2;
       if (arr[mid] == x) {
           return x;
       }
       else if (x <= arr[mid]) {
           end = mid - 1;
       }
       else {
           start = mid + 1; 
       }
   }
   return mid;
}   
  public static void printKclosest(int arr[], int x, int k)
{
    int element = findElement(arr, x); 
    int count = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int difference = Math.abs(arr[i] - element);
            while (count < k) {
            if (difference > 0) {
              System.out.println(arr[i]);
              count++;
            }
        }
    }    
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
   int[] array = {-1, 3, 5, 2, 1, 7};
   sortArray(array);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
   printKclosest(array, 2, 3);
}
```

}

for find the k nearest elements, i was thinking I could use a for loop to go through each element in the array and subtract from the element that's X and print the number of k elements that have the smallest difference, but the output I'm getting is -1 k amount of times.

Comment: This is an algorithm problem, so it makes sense to post your algorithm.  Your algorithm as it is, is:  for each array element, print out that element as many times as the difference between it and X.  So it makes sense that it isn't working.  Plan it out in English and _then_ convert to Java.

Answer (score 1):

function `findElement` returns x **value** if x exists but **index** of potential place for x if it does not present in array.

So in the second case your comparison `int difference = Math.abs(arr[i] - element);` has no sense

How to overcome: change in findElement

```
  int end = arr.length - 1;

  return x;
  to
  return mid;
```

and

```
  difference = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[element]);
```

But approach to get k closest numbers is completely wrong. Suggestion:

Set L index to `element` and R index to `element+1`
Compare abs differences for L and R. Output smaller. If smaller is for R, decrement L, otherwise increment R. Repeat k times (don't forget about array range)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. Even when I search for an integer that's in the array

Comment: Added another correction in binary search. Check result of findElement. Seach for k closest numbers is completely wrong. I'll write suggestion later

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MBo's great suggestion for outputting the k closest elements using L and R pointers, you could also solve this without sorting the array in O(n log k) time by iterating over the array once and keeping the chosen elements in a heap, each time removing the farthest (k+1)th element.